# Easiest was to share group project code written in MatLab

Tags: matlab, file-sharing

We are working on a group project written in MatLab. We all need to be able to access and write the same program, sometime simultaneously. We are working on a scientific Linux distribution. We are all physicists so we would rather find a very simple - ideally GUI, solution.

It sounds like GitHub would enable us to write simultaneously and merge mismatched code but it seems so complicated. We don't really understand the push/pull/fork/commit terminology and we would rather not study it if there is an easier option.

What is the path of least resistance for a group project in Matlab?

Comment: Coming from a telecommunucation engineering background, I found the "_path of least resistance_" wording amusing :-) (Sorry that I can't answer to your question)

Comment: To be honest, GitHub is becoming a kind of norm, so it would be best for you to use GitHub. It does seem complicated at a glance, but for your purposes, you will only be needing roughly 6 commands, which you can type into your cmd window. The beauty of GitHub is that it does not make stupid mistakes

Comment: If you want easy: Use Dropbox or something similar. If you don't want to mess up the code unintentionally you should definitely go for github. It's actually really easy! I don't think it will take you longer than an hour to get the basic concepts. There are even lots of [GUIs](http://git-scm.com/download/gui/linux) available!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I regularly use Subversion for group MATLAB projects. It has what I find a slightly simpler workflow than Git/GitHub.

The latest versions of MATLAB integrate directly with Subversion, so you can check things in and out directly from within the MATLAB workspace. Alternatively you can use TortoiseSVN, which integrates within Windows Explorer (I believe there is an equivalent for Linux as well).

However, I'll speak bluntly - Git and GitHub are really not that hard, and I'm pretty sure that anyone who's clever enough to be a physicist working with MATLAB is clever enough to understand them as well. Although Subversion is a bit simpler to learn, Git and GitHub have a lot of advantages, they integrate well with many other services, and they're just overall kind of better. The latest versions of MATLAB integrate directly with them in the same way as with Subversion.